# Proving $n\text{P}(Y>n) \rightarrow 0$ implies $n\text{P}(Y> \epsilon n) \rightarrow 0$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ for

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am currently stuck at the following question: If we know that $Y$ is a random variable in $\text{R}$ that satisfies $n\ \text{P} (Y>n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Can we conclude that $n \  \text{P}(Y>n \epsilon)$ will also converge to zero for any $\epsilon >0$? If so, which theorem can we employ to prove this? Thanks for any hints or insights provided!

Comment: here n is integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the hypothesis $n P(Y > n) \to 0$ implies $n \epsilon P(Y > n \epsilon) \to 0$, from which you can obtain the desired result.

Comment: but the sequence $a_n$ = $n \text{P} (Y>n)$ goes to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$ does not imply the function $f(x) = x \text{P} (Y>x)$ goes to zero as $x \rightarrow \infty$ right? so how does that implication hold?

Comment: Note that $P(Y > x)$ is decreasing in $x$. So for $x >0$, we have $ P(Y > n+1) \le P(Y> x) \le P(Y > n)$, where $n = \lfloor x\rfloor$. So $x P(Y> x) \le x P(Y > \lfloor x\rfloor) \le  \lfloor x\rfloor  P(Y > \lfloor x\rfloor)  + P(Y > \lfloor x\rfloor)  $. Now take $x\to \infty$.